# Disable console autologin on Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, login

I've uninstall the GUI, and I also want to disable automatic login at the command line. I've read that you should use the raspi-config utility to do this. I select the first option and reboot, and it has no effect.

How does one "do this manually"?

Answer (score 8):

Autologin is performed as part of `systemd`'s `getty` target:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Sep 24 18:14 getty@tty1.service -> /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service
```

The `raspi-config` simply manipulates this symlink. To switch to manual login, execute (as root):

```
ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service \
 /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

To switch back to automatic login, do:

```
ln -fs /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service \
 /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

I wanted a system with no console prompt on `tty1`, so I removed this symlink altogether.

Comment: If you have removed the default user "pi", you must also update "/etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service". Update the username in the line `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin USERNAME --noclear %I $TERM`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by looking at exactly what raspi-config does.

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
```

This is B1 Console in raspi-config. For other alternatives go to do_boot_behaviour in raspi-config source file. To find source file, use:

```
which raspi-config
```

Answer (score 0):

The autologin process is controlled by getty@tty1.service. And the config file `autologin.conf` under the folder `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/` is a [drop-in file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/getty#Prompt_only_the_password_for_a_default_user_in_virtual_console_login). You can just change the file name to `autologin.conf.bak` then the username and password prompt will show up on the next boot.