# Disable autologin on tty1 on stretch 9.9

Tags: raspbian, script

I found [this answere](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38203/101813) but it doesnt work anymore.
How does it work on the new version?

Comment: Can you please explain what your problem is without the necessity to read another question?

Comment: My problem is written in the title, I want to now how to "Disable autologin on tty1 on strech 9.9"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The autologin.conf file for tty1 must be deleted:

`sudo rm /etc/systemd/System/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf`.

Comment: What you are talking about?

Comment: Why -1? This is the solution to the question. The file does the autologin on tty1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it is preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer and a command; nobody understand what you mean without deeply research your question. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or you risk to get down votes.

Comment: A detailed answer is [posted here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17830633/6340496).